R script DONT export when table is empty
I have a table that is updating every week. Sometimes there are no values in the table. When there are no values, I don't want to export the table.
week <- unique(dataset$Week)
year <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y")
Table <- paste0("\\\\Server\\data\\2024\\Test ", week, "-", year, ".csv")
write.table(dataset, file = Table, sep = ";", na = "", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE).

How can I change the code so the file isn't exporting when there are empty values.

Try
if(nrow(dataset)) 
  write.table(dataset, file=Table, sep=";", na="", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)

